# MacOS Server Profile Manager slow to push changes

Tags: mac-osx-server

DNS is fine and I can see in the logs that the server is talking to the laptops but changes sit as 'pending' for a couple of hours before successfully pushing to the machines.

In the Service Helper log I have this

```
[2017/01/30 08:47:50.518] Building missing profile caches failed! (2)
```

In /Library/Logs/ProfileManager/profilemanager.log I have this

```
[2017/01/30 08:47:50.320] E: ProfileCacheBuilder: Exception caught Couldn't find DataFile with ID=1:
/Applications/Server.app/Contents/ServerRoot/usr/share/devicemgr/backend/app/models/profile.rb:178:in `generate_profile_cache'
/Applications/Server.app/Contents/ServerRoot/usr/share/devicemgr/backend/app/models/profile.rb:301:in `update_profile_cache'
/Applications/Server.app/Contents/ServerRoot/usr/share/devicemgr/backend/app/models/profile.rb:151:in `update_one_profile_cache'
/Applications/Server.app/Contents/ServerRoot/usr/share/devicemgr/backend/lib/profile_cache_builder.rb:26:in `block in run'
/Applications/Server.app/Contents/ServerRoot/usr/share/devicemgr/backend/lib/profile_cache_builder.rb:26:in `run'
/Applications/Server.app/Contents/ServerRoot/usr/share/devicemgr/backend/lib/profile_cache_builder.rb:36:in `<top (required)>'
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: I  admin hundreds of Macs, mostly iMacs, and I have to say, that my personal opinion is that Profile Manager is completely broken.  I could send you dozens of log files that make no sense.  I will post an answer which is almost a non-answer, but has solved my own orgainzations' problems, in the true Apple tradition (of hardware upgarde).

Answer (score 0):

In every case I've personally seen, those type of issues are related to hardware being not supported or overworked.

I would suggest reviewing [this guide by Apple](https://ssl.apple.com/xserve/pdf/L422277A_Xserve_Guide.pdf) where you can clearly see the limitations and expectations of what OSX Server, in today's market, is meant to run.  I saw log entries like yours, while trying to run about 300 users in combination with several others "services" on a single Mac mini, and if you read the above carefully, you'll see that the mini's are only spec'd for a single service each (*well, basically*).

If this doesn't help please comment back with much more specific hardware info, and number of users, etc., and I can update the answer, and we can all gladly further troubleshoot!

Comment: Resource usage looks pretty low on this machine. Currently got profile manager running for 14 machines and TimeMachine for 6.

It does also run Adobe and MacOS update server but still doesn't seem to be struggling. I guess if this is how MacOS server works then we'll get used to it!

Comment: Well if you include the Adobe services, which are very heavy (time machine also is very heavy), you've just listed 4 services, where the document I posted above says the Mac Minis were designed to host single services.  On the other hand if you or anyone else knew what "run" referes to above (is it the mount '/run', for example) maybe that means a very specific temp resource is overwhelmed that you can easily get to the bottom of, and have loads of most resources still left...